# Shifting texture/Animating textures, how to make glass ball with shapes inside it?

Tags: animation, texturing, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make the ball shift from one texture to other like on example link and I dont have any idea how to bite into it.

Also I was wandering if can I animate glass ball with texture or do I have to make ball transparent and animate with shapes inside it.

Or maybe there is way using geometry nodes? Total rookie in geometry nodes.

https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/6bd07c143591313.6283af89eba6a.gif?fbclid=IwAR3NYJe8V4bkVS48Z9z1Haq9kPXE5IpdbtsxfVgVXzp5UFTfO_-I4MaDLIw

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Is it enough to use a shader mixRGB node and animate the factor between 2 textures? If you need a transition, you can always animate a gradient using keyframes on a color ramp